# Constrain MKMapView to it's MKOverlayView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I have a MKMapView with a series the overlaid tiles for a custom map. I want to limit the scrolling and zooming within the bounds of the overlay view. Is this possible?

Comment: Try this answer: [Restrict MKMapView Scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119117/restrict-mkmapview-scrolling)