# Mapkit draghino

Tags: ios, mapkit, drag

This may sound dumb but I did some research and I am looking for a function that is called WHILE the map is being dragged not after.

Is there any delegate functions because I couldnt find any.

Comment: Try using pan and pinch gesture recognizers instead of (or in addition to) the regionWill/DidChangeAnimated delegate methods.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922422/keep-two-mkmapviews-showing-the-same-region for an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

What about `mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:`? From the docs:

> During scrolling, this method may be called many times to report updates to the map position.

Comment: That only gets called one the drag begins . I need something that is called while dragging occurs. I might have to implement my own with NSTimer, I just wanted to know if there was anything before i reinvented the wheel.

Comment: Ah, I see. Looking around SO, there seem to be a few questions about observing the map's region using KVO and digging for the map's scroll view, but a timer is what people end up using.