# Constrain MKMapView within overlay bounds

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

Can anyone give pointers as to how we can restrict to scroll a mapview beyond overlay bounds. Overlay size is greater than iPhone screen size.

I have tried a number of solutions available on net but none is satisfactory.

Using the solution provided here -
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/59028-nsnotification-sendevent.html (**warning**, link throws a malware alert)

It does restrict to some extent but if we scroll it fast, it starts showing the map beyond the overlay.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [this answer to "Restrict MKMapView scrolling"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119117/restrict-mkmapview-scrolling/4126011#4126011)?

Comment: Yes but my overlay size is bigger than the iPhone screen size, will it effect? Also while I keep holding my finger down, it shows the map beyond the overlay till I release my finger from the mapview. Is this expected from the solution described here?

Comment: Overlay being bigger than the screen doesn't matter.  Temporarily seeing a little beyond the overlay is expected and possibly unavoidable (eg. user could try to zoom far out and then the code snaps it back to overlay's bounds).  I'm not sure why it's a problem if the area outside is visible for a little bit but you could try putting another large overlay (with a hole where your real overlay is) that covers up the map surrounding it with a solid color.

Comment: The link in your question throws a malware alert in chrome, I've edited your post to include a warning. The edit can be reverted once the link no longer alerts.