# Inverted MKPolygon (Inside Out)

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay

I am working with MKPolygon and MKPolygonView as a map overlay for the first time. I can place a shape over an area, and the fill color fills the interior of the polygon.

I am looking for a way to put the fill everywhere on my map except the interior of the polygon. Does anyone have an idea how to do this easily?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to do this is by making a polygon overlay that covers the whole world and specifying the part(s) you don't want to fill as "interior polygon(s)".

This is done using the [`polygonWithCoordinates:count:interiorPolygons:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKPolygon_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009717-CH1-SW6) class method of `MKPolygon`.  There's also `polygonWithPoints:count:interiorPolygons:` if you have `MKMapPoint`s instead of coordinates.

You pass an `NSArray` of  `MKPolygon`s for the `interiorPolygons` parameter.  These areas will not be filled in with the `fillColor`.

For sample code, see this question: [Showing Specific Region Using MapKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679499/showing-specific-region-using-mapkit)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice that the parameter `interiorPolygon` was an array of MKPolygons until you showed me the example. It works great.