# Boundaries to scrolling of mapview- ios

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, region

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MKMapView - Limit map scroll to a square overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152244/mkmapview-limit-map-scroll-to-a-square-overlay)

Is there a way to limit the scrolling of a map to scroll only within the boundaries of a specific country (region)? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol has a `-mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:` method that you can implement in your map delegate. Unfortunately, it's not `...ShouldChangeAnimated:`, so you don't get to return `NO` to prevent the change, but what you *can* do is to set the map region yourself when the user scrolls beyond the area that you want to display.