# Prevent MKMapView from scrolling horizontally endlessly

Tags: ios, ios7, mkmapview, mkoverlay

How do I prevent  MKMapView from  Infinite horizontal scrolling.
I am using a overlay to show a custom map

```
MKTileOverlay *overlay = [[MKTileOverlay alloc]initWithURLTemplate:tileTemplate];
[mapView addOverlay:overlay];
 mapView.visibleMapRect = MKMapRectWorld;
```

when the user scrolls horizontal and reaches the End of MKMapRectWorld the map gets repeated.

I looked at [Restrict MKMapView scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119117/restrict-mkmapview-scrolling)
but the code looks rather complicated and one can see a little bit of the repeated map before the animation scrolls back.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

BOOL mapContainsOverlay = MKMapRectContainsRect(MKMapRectWorld,self.mapView.visibleMapRect);

if (!mapContainsOverlay) {


    [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:MKMapRectWorld animated:NO];
}
```

}
//or regionWillchangeAninmate

Any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Since the map is not a child of UIScrollView, you can't limit the map scrolling on one direction directly. Maybe try adding a transparent scrollview on top of the map view and forwarding the touches you deem to be adequate for the behavior you want.