# How to set bounds to the visiblemap in object c

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

I am trying to limit the user to and specific area of the map using a MKMapView. Even if he is trying to move the content of the map, it just doesnt allow the user.

Any ideas?

Ty

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: i found a way ty, it was kind easy

We just need to call delegate method

(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated

and the set the region of the map with 

[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

Comment: the problem with that way is that the user cant zoom the map.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119117/restrict-mkmapview-scrolling