# Incorrect size after setVisibleMapRect iOS

Tags: ios

I have problem setting a new visibleMapRect to my mapView (self.map).

```
       MKMapRect newMapRect;
       newMapRect.origin = MKMapPointMake(newXValue, newYValue);
       newMapRect.size = MKMapSizeMake(width*, height*);
       [self.map setVisibleMapRect:newMapRect];
```

For some width* or height* values, the size of the self.map does not get set. Like after above code.

```
this self.map.visibleMapRect.size.height is not same as height*
or
this self.map.visible.MapRect.size.width is not same as width*
```

So self.map.origin would have the newXValue and newYValue, but self.map.size would not always have the same width and height value.

This is so frustrating. Why doesn't the size always gets set too?

What I am ultimately trying to do is limit a space where users can scroll the mapView. When user scrolls outside of my bounds, I call visibleMapRect with the current height and width values, but with different origin coordinates so that the user can come back to the zone where scrolling is allowed.

Comment: What are you trying to do really (eg. show group of annotations, show city/country, other)?  As the docs say, `visibleMapRect` is the same as the `region` but using different units.  As the docs also say for the `setRegion` method: ["the map may adjust the value ... so that it fits the visible area"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205-CH3-SW40).  This also applies to `setVisibleMapRect` although it's not explicitly stated.

Comment: Basically, the map view will not distort the map so it adjusts the requested rect/region to avoid it.  By the way, you say "height is not same as width*".  Do you mean "height is not same as height*"?

Comment: Yea I edited the mistake. So is there a way to prevent the map view from not adjusting the requested rect/region? I want the map view to adjust no matter what, because if you just adjust as the way I requested, everything is fine.

Comment: And is there a documentation I can read about "the map view will not distort the map so it adjusts the requested rect/region to avoid it" because I am not sure how to avoid it. It is just nonsensical, when I change the value, and it didn't get changed!

Comment: It is not nonsensical. The map view has an aspect ratio. Your height/width have an aspect ratio. If they don't match, the map wins; the map is not going to show the earth squeezed and distorted in some impossible way! It knows better than you do how to display a map correctly.

Comment: But the thing is, I'm not inserting new height and width values. I zoom the map and scroll, and I call set visibleMapRect with the current height and width values, but with different origin coordinates. What I am ultimately trying to do is limit a space where users can scroll the mapView. So I am giving the sensical height and width values; the map is giving me the values in the first place. So please down vote me. This is actually legitimate question that needs an answer, matt.

Comment: I meant *dont down vote me. :)

Comment: When you change the origin, the map may not be able to use the same dimensions because the Earth is curved and the map is a 2D projection of a curved surface.  To limit the space where users can scroll, try this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119117/restrict-mkmapview-scrolling

Comment: Your suggestion is so helpful. I have a better approach to limit the space where users can scroll than your link. I just have to get this right. When I change the origin, is there a way I can change the dimensions as slight as possible to acceptable values so that the visibleMapRect get indeed set?

Comment: I hope you could answer this question Anna since you are an expert at MKMapView stuffs :) I would really appreciate it.